# VBA to replace cell text that starts with ### to = in 3 different columns without affecting rows 1 to 15

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, replace

I'm not very familiar with VBA, but am in need of a macro that would replace **###** to **=** for columns B, F, and J without affecting rows 1 to 15.

I found the below code as my starting point, but can't seem to adjust it to my situation, or if this would even work for my situation...

this code was replacing everything in **B** that was not empty to **Title** starting at B2

```
Sub replace_text
Dim lrow As Long
Dim rng As Range

    lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'Detect last data entry row in Column B.
    
    For Each rng In Range("B2:B" & lrow)
        If rng <> "" Then
            rng = "Title"
        End If
    Next rng

End Sub
```

essentially, my goal is to replace every occurrences of text strings that start with **###** with **=** without affecting the remainder of the strings.

everything in column B, F, and J starting at row 16 would start with **###** but do not have the same text after the **###**.

other columns would also have **###** at the start but would need to remain intact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `Worksheet.Evaluate`: Replace Text

```vb
Sub ReplaceText()

    Const FIRST_ROW As Long = 16
    Const COLUMNS_RANGE As String = "B:B,F:F,J:J"
    Const BEGINS_WITH_STRING As String = "###"
    Const REPLACE_STRING  As String = "="
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim rg As Range
    
    With ws.UsedRange
        Set rg = .Resize(.Rows.Count + .Row - FIRST_ROW).Offset(FIRST_ROW - 1)
    End With
    
    Dim arg As Range, aAddress As String, Formula As String
       
    For Each arg In Intersect(rg, ws.Range(COLUMNS_RANGE)).Areas
        aAddress = arg.Address
        Formula = "IF(LEFT(" & aAddress & "," & Len(BEGINS_WITH_STRING) _
            & ")=""" & BEGINS_WITH_STRING & """," & "SUBSTITUTE(" _
            & aAddress & ",""" & BEGINS_WITH_STRING & """,""" _
            & REPLACE_STRING & """,1)," & aAddress & ")"
        'Debug.Print Formula
        arg.Value = ws.Evaluate(Formula)
    Next arg
    MsgBox "Text replaced.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: you sir, are a SUPERSTAR!

thank you!

Comment: would there be a way to add code at the start, to copy the cells in the row to the right, starting at row 16 **(paste C:C to B:B, G:G to F:F, K:K to J:J)** and **paste them as values** prior to this **replace Text code**?